# syntax error, unexpected token "<" (View: /Users/pathparakh/Projects/store/resources/views/product.blade.php) in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

There are an error showing when i add **@if ({{Auth::user()->utype}} == "ADM")** Line of code in product.blade.php.

```
</head>
@if ({{Auth::user()->utype}} == "ADM")

    <body>
        
    </body>

@endif
```

This is my controller named ProductController.

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('product', compact('products'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('product');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'brand' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
        'size' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'image' => $new_name,
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'size' => $request->input('size'),
        'type' => $request->input('type'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'detail' => $request->input('detail'),
        'brand' => $request->input('brand'),
    );

    Product::create($form_data);
    return redirect()->route('product.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnzF.png)
Please help me to solve the mistake.

Comment: you dont need to use blade echo statement on condition `@if (auth::user()->utype == "ADM")` is pretty fine

Comment: After running this , It shows an error Attempt to read property "utype" on null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using blade directive, so no need to put {{}}, inside @if or any other directive try this

```
@if (Auth::user()->utype == "ADM")

    <body>
        
    </body>

@endif
```

Comment: After running this , It shows an error   Attempt to read property "utype" on null

Comment: what is `utype` in your user model ? column or method ?

Comment: utype is a coloum stands for user type (admin or user)

Comment: Are you logged in your application ? Auth::user() will run only if you are authenticated user, so could you please try by logging in again.

Comment: Sorry it my mistake i loged out,  thanks for helping @Vipertecpro

Comment: :D Always happy to help, Let us know if you need us to resolve issues :D